# Katalon Studio: How to create VerifyElementText Test Case for MTOM Enabled SOAP Web Services?

Tags: web-services, soap, katalon-studio

I have created Web Service Project. Following is the Script of my Test Case, which verifies element text as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Web+Services#WebServices-HandleResponsemessages):

```
import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS

def response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('ProductById'))
WS.verifyElementText(response, "Product.Reference", "MyReference")
```

When I’m running this test case I’m getting the error: `[FAILED] - Unable to verify element text (Root cause: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.)`

Then I have used: `com.kms.katalon.core.util.KeywordUtil#logInfo` to see the `response.responseText`, I have received, which was:

```
--uuid:4e39ea48-6560-46b7-a30c-201dfaf98f51
Content-Type: application/xop+xml; charset=UTF-8; type="text/xml";
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID: <root.message@cxf.apache.org>

<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soap:Body><ns2:getProductResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mycompany.com/"><Product><Reference>VW3A8306R</Reference></Product></ns2:getProductResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
--uuid:4e39ea48-6560-46b7-a30c-201dfaf98f51--
```

The Web Service I am testing `MTOM` enabled. That’s why the response text is of that format.

How to create test case in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split  content and then continue working on that instead. Below are Katalon Studio scripts to help you in this case:

```
   import static com.kms.katalon.core.testobject.ObjectRepository.findTestObject
   import com.kms.katalon.core.webservice.keyword.WSBuiltInKeywords as WS

   def response = WS.sendRequest(findTestObject('ProductById'))
   response.responseText = (response.responseText =~ '<soap:Envelope.*
   </soap:Envelope>')[0]
   WS.verifyElementText(response, "getProductResponse.Product.Reference", 
   "MyPreference")
```